# use other layout instead of framelayout in a drawerlayout

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, android-fragments

i have to use a drawer menu in my android app, in google's example they use a `framelayout` (i see that people generally uses `framelayout`), but i tried to replace it with a `linearlayout` this way:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

but graphical layout designer (in eclipse) doesn't allow me to build the user interface, in a past attempt to use a drawer menu i tried to add views at hand but graphical designer doesn't render the user interface and application crashes if i open that activity.

am i required to use a framelayout? (with a fragment?) i'm ok using fragments but i would like to use a regular user interface since i don't need the power of fragments in this app

Comment: Using linear layout wont make your app crash, i recommend you to use linear layout.

Comment: You need to change in the code as well (wherever its calling `content_frame` as FrameLayout)

Comment: the problem is that the interface is not rendered even in preview, and the code still doesn't have references to the linear layout